# Android what is the resource name of the default window background color of the current scheme/style

Tags: android

I tried to find it, maybe it's too obvious :) but how is the resource named of the "default window background color" (that pale white in holo light for instance) to be used in xml design?

```
    android:background="<help me out here>"
```

Of course, just not giving the background attribute at all will reset, I know that, but on some shapes we need this background color as fill color, so I need to know the resource name of it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks for downvoting... why did i deserve this? oO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. It's @android:color/background_light respectively @android:color/background_dark depending on scheme.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<style name="CustomMaterialTheme.Base"   parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>  //primary color of action bar
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> //dark is the background color
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>//text color
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>  //background color of the app
```

Hope it helps.Thanks Refer here i found a beautiful tutorial http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-material-design/